# React & Deck.GL: Add default props to each child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deck.gl

I'm working on a configurable set of map layers with Deck.GL & React. I have a `BaseMap` component that I'll pass layers of data to as react children.

Currently, I have this:

BaseMap:

```
export const BaseMap = ({ latitude = 0, longitude = 0, zoom = 4, children }) => {
    const deckProps = {
        initialViewState: { latitude, longitude, zoom },
        controller: true
    };
    return (
        <DeckGL {...deckProps}>
            {children}
            <StaticMap />
        </DeckGL>
    );
};
```

And it's used like this:

```
<BaseMap>
    <ScatterplotLayer
        data={scatterData}
        getPosition={getPositionFn}
        getRadius={1}
        radiusUnits={'pixels'}
        radiusMinPixels={1}
        radiusMaxPixels={100}
        filled={true}
        getFillColor={[255, 255, 255]}
    />
    <TextLayer
        data={textData}
        getPosition={getPositionFn}
        getColor={[255, 0, 0]}
        getText={getTextFn}
    />
</BaseMap>
```

This is okay, but I want to add default props to each child.

### Attempt 1

I've tried this in `BaseMap`, but get the error `cannot assign to read only property props of object #<Object>`:

```
...
return (
    <DeckGL {...deckProps}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (c) => {
            const defaultProps = {
                loaders: [CSVLoader]
            }
            c.props = { ...defaultProps, ...c.props };
            return c;
        })}
    </DeckGL>
);
```

### Attempt 2

I've also tried creating a wrapper component for each type of layer, but get the error `Cannot call a class as a function`:

wrapper:

```
export const ScatterplotLayerWrapper = (props) => {
    const defaultScatterProps = {
        loaders: [CSVLoader]
    };
    const scatterLayerProps = {
        ...defaultScatterProps,
        ...props
    };
    return <ScatterplotLayer {...scatterLayerProps} />;
};
```

used like this:

```
<BaseMap>
    <ScatterplotLayerWrapper
        data={scatterData}
        getPosition={getPositionFn}
    />
</BaseMap>
```

I suspect the problem with this second attempt has something to do with the [caveat here](https://deck.gl/docs/get-started/using-with-react#using-jsx-with-deckgl-layers).

### Solution?

I can imagine two types of solutions (and obviously, there may be others!):

- correct method for checking the layer type & modifying child props depending on the type, or something similar - is this possible?

or

- Some way to convince react/deck.gl that `ScatterplotLayer` *will be* a child of `Deck.GL`, even if it isn't in `ScatterplotLayerWrapper`. (This one seems less likely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion came from a mis-understanding of how `deck.gl`'s React component works & what those `<ScatterplotLayer>` components really are (they're not react components).

Deck.gl's react component, `DeckGL`, intercepts all children and determines if  they are in fact "layers masquerading as react elements" (see [code](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/8e2167c7961bb5a54b3f96af151f1742d1a20e26/modules/react/src/utils/extract-jsx-layers.js#L27)). It then builds layers from each of those "elements" and passes them back to `DeckGL`'s `layers` property.

They look like react components, but really aren't. They can't be rendered on their own in a React context. They can't be rendered outside of the `DeckGL` component at all, because they're still just plain deck.gl layers.

The solution here is to create a new map layer class just like you might in any other context (not a React component wrapping a layer). Docs for that are [here](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/custom-layers).

```
class WrappedTextLayer extends CompositeLayer {
    renderLayers() { // a method of `Layer` classes
        // special logic here
        return [new TextLayer(this.props)];
    }
}
WrappedTextLayer.layerName = 'WrappedTextLayer';
WrappedTextLayer.defaultProps = {
    getText: (): string => 'x',
    getSize: (): number => 32,
    getColor: [255, 255, 255]
};

export { WrappedTextLayer };
```

This new layer can then be used in the `BaseMap` component (or the un-wrapped `DeckGL` component`) like this:

```
<BaseMap>
    <WrappedTextLayer
        data={dataUrl}
        getPosition={(d) => [d.longitude, d.latitude]}
    />
</BaseMap>
```

In addition, the exact same layer can be passed to `DeckGL` as a layer prop:

```
<DeckGL
    layers={[
        new WrappedTextLayer({
            data: dataUrl,
            getPosition: (d) => [d.longitude, d.latitude]
        })
    ]}
></DeckGL>
```

Modifying the `BaseMap` component a little will allow it to accept layers either as JSX-like children, *or* via the `layers` prop as well:

```
export const BaseMap = ({ latitude = 0, longitude = 0, zoom = 4, children, layers }) => {
    const deckProps = {
        initialViewState: { latitude, longitude, zoom },
        controller: true,
        layers
    };
    return (
        <DeckGL {...deckProps}>
            {children && !layers ? children : null}
            <StaticMap />
        </DeckGL>
    );
};
```